# Windows Installer upgrade: how to detect previous version

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using wix to write my installer. To make things simple, I am only dealing with major upgrades. My code looks like this:

```
<Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="SOME-GUID">
  <Package Id="*">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>
```

Now I want to add a custom action in the next release, but I only want to run the custom action if we're upgrading from a certain range of versions. I studied the verbose log of an upgrade and found out that `FindRelatedProducts` sets a couple of properties: `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` and `MIGRATE`. They look like they are the product GUID of the previous installation. Is there a way to find out the version as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different properties based on range of versions using Upgrade element. FildRelatedProducts standard action executes the same as well.

```
    <Upgrade Id='PUT-GUID-2-HERE'>
    <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='SELFFOUND'
        Minimum='1.0.1' IncludeMinimum='yes'
        Maximum='1.0.1' IncludeMaximum='yes' />
    <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='NEWERFOUND'
        Minimum='1.0.1' IncludeMinimum='no' />
    </Upgrade>
```

Comment: Does that mean I need to provide a product GUID instead of use *? I thought it was preferable to use * so that each version gets their own GUID? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. you can use *